# GD::Graph Fonts and Legends

Tags: perl, graph, fonts, gd, legend

I have a cumulative GD bar graph in a perl script that I can't seem to change the title font to larger and bold.

Also, more importantly, how can you add a legend to a graph? I've read that there may not be a way to do so in the actual graph but added in with GD::Graph::Map.

Any idea on how to go about doing either of these? I couldn't find a single answer that applied anywhere else.

Thanks

```
my $graph = GD::Graph::bars->new (900,450);
$graph->set(
 x_label         => 'X Label',
 y_label         => 'Y label',
 title           => 'Title',

 t_margin        => 5,
 b_margin        => 2,
 l_margin        => 5,
 r_margin        => 5,

 y_min_value     => 0,
 y_max_value     => 1200,
 y_tick_number   => 8,
 y_label_skip    => 3,
 cumulate        => 1,

 dclrs           => [qw(#4f81bd #70AD47 #5b9bd5 #FFC000 #ED7D31 #AFABAB #9E480E #997300 #264478 #ac63e3 #FF7171 #d571ce)],
 fgclr           => black,
 textclr         => black,
 labelclr        => black,
 axislabelclr    => black,

 x_labels_vertical => 1,
 y_long_ticks      => 1,
 line_width      => 4,
 bar_spacing     => 10,
 transparent     => 0,
) or warn $graph->error;


$tmp_trend_file = 'graph.png';
open(IMG, ">$tmp_trend_file") or die $!;
binmode IMG;
print IMG $graph->plot(\@data)->png();
close IMG;  
print "<p><img src=$tmp_trend_file border=1><p>\n";
```

Comment: GD does have some built-in fonts, but it also has support for TrueType fonts which give much better results.  There are some examples in this [slide set](http://wellington.pm.org/archive/201002/grant-gd-graph/)

Comment: Do you know how to add them in though? That's what I can't figure out.

Comment: Also that link is to only a single cover slide.

Comment: I guess it's not obvious, there is a link to the next slide, or you can use arrow keys or PgDn/PgUp. Using a TrueType font requires specifying the pathname of the .ttf or .otf file.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a legend and change the font with the following code:

`$graph->set_legend_font(GD::gdFontTiny);
$graph->set_legend(split(' ',$legend));`